# реализовать функцию print(get_text(text = "hello world"))

Tags: python, python-3.x

Код работает при `print(get_text("hello world"))`, но не работает при `print(get_text(text = "hello world"))`

```
def bold(func):
    def get_text_bold(*arg):
        return "{1}{0}{2}".format(func(*arg), '<b>', '</b>')
    return get_text_bold


def italic(func):
    def get_text_italic(*arg):
        return "{1}{0}{2}".format(func(*arg), '<i>', '</i>')
    return get_text_italic


def underline(func):
    def get_text_underline(*arg):
        return "{1}{0}{2}".format(func(*arg), '<u>', '</u>')
    return get_text_underline


@bold
@italic
@underline
def get_text(text):
    return text


print(get_text(text = "hello world"))
```

Comment: у меня все работает, какую именно у вас ошибку выдает? какую версию питона используете?

Comment: get_text_bold() got an unexpected keyword argument 'text' вот ошибка. Версия 3.9

Comment: в версии 3.8 так тоже не работает, но если заменить `*arg` на `**arg` срабатывает

Comment: Спасибо, нашел ошибку и исправил